# global and local variable on the event handler function

Tags: javascript

This is my javascript code

```
window.onload = function(event){
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    img[0].onmousedown = function(event){          
        alert(five);
        var five = 5;            
    };      
};
```

I expected it to be alert the number '5' on the second time i clicked the image, but it keep on alerting undefined.Why?
Then I move out the alert statement outside the onmousedown function, it display nothing:

```
window.onload = function(event){
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    img[0].onmousedown = function(event){          
        var five = 5;            
    };      
    alert(five);     
};
```

Then I thought the problem is that it is that a local variable is created inside the onmousedown function. So I just create a global variable by omiting the 'var', but it seems like it doesn't work too, why???

```
window.onload = function(event){
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    img[0].onmousedown = function(event){          
         var five = 5;           
    };      
    alert(five);     
};
```

Comment: In all cases, alert show variable before its initialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "hoisting". All variable declaration are "bubbled" up to a function start. But value assignment stays in place

The following code

```
function() {
    alert(five);
    var five = 5;
}
```

Will be executed as follows:

```
function() {
    var five;
    alert(five);
    five = 5;            
}
```

Every time click occurs, a new variable is created, so, the result of previous call is discarded.

Seems like you need a global variable if you need to alert `undefined` at first call and `5` at all other calls:

```
var five; // Declaration here
window.onload = function(event){
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    img[0].onmousedown = function(event){          
        alert(five);
        five = 5;            
    };      
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.onload = function(event){
       var five=0;
         var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
       img[0].onmousedown = function(event){           
                if(five)alert(five);
                five = 5;            
       };      

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In first case you firstly alert variable before declaring it

```
img[0].onmousedown = function(event){  
      var five = 5;   //first should be declaration        
      alert(five); //then you should alert it

 };
```

in second case you want to alert the local variable outside the block that is why it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

first assign a variable `var five = 5;` then alert it `alert(five);` just swap those two lines in your first code :)

Comment: by that it will alert 5 on the first time too

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mrdvJ

```
window.onload = function(event){
     var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),
         five;
   img[0].onmousedown = function(event) {

            alert(five);           
            five = 5;

   };          
};
```

This code will let give you undefined as first, and five at second execution. To have 5 all the time simply execute alert after assigning a value.